# Add an element to each list in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
a = [(1,2,3,4), (2,3,2,2), (33,221,22,1) ...]
```

and I want to add for each item in the list a 5th value, for example:

```
new_a = [(1,2,3,4,"new"), (2,3,2,2,"new"), (33,221,22,1,"new") ...]
```

How can I do that because a.list or a.add freeze my computer.

```
for item in a:
  a.add("new") or a.append("new")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner items are not lists, they are tuples. Tuples are immutable. Therefore, you probably need to create new tuples that contain the values you want:

```
new_a = [x + ('new',) for x in a]
```

This code iterates through all tuples present in a and for each one creates a new tuple consisting of the values of the original, plus the value `'new'` *(the value `('new',)` is a tuple literal: it creates a new tuple with one value)*.

In the end, all the values created are assigned to the new list.

Comment: yeah... tuples... That was my mistake :(. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`

```
>>> map(lambda x: x + ('new',), a)
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 'new'), (2, 3, 2, 2, 'new'), (33, 221, 22, 1, 'new')]
```